# How to pivot columns with multiple grouping columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a large panel data set resembling the following:

[image]

I am looking to reshape the data and add columns that reflect values of the `Score` and `Distance` columns for every fifth value of Game (grouped by `Player` and `Year`). So the final data set would look like:

[image]

Normally, I would do this using the match command:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Player, Year) %>% 
  mutate(ScoreGame0 =  Score[match(Game, 0)]) %>%
  mutate(ScoreGame5 =  Score[match(Game, 5)])
```

And so on. However, given that my final data set is much larger than this (involving way more observations and variables to reshape), I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. Perhaps it is possible to write a function? (I have tried and failed miserably at that).

Initial data:

```
structure(list(Player = c("Lebron James", "Lebron James", "Lebron James", 
"Lebron James", "Lebron James", "Lebron James", "Lebron James", 
"Lebron James", "Lebron James", "Lebron James", "Lebron James", 
"Lebron James", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", 
"Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", 
"Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry", "Steph Curry"), 
    Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
    2021L, 2021L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), 
    Game = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Score = c(32L, 
    23L, 33L, 27L, 29L, 27L, 44L, 22L, 33L, 54L, 65L, 12L, 45L, 
    48L, 44L, 51L, 65L, 76L, 76L, 67L, 56L, 44L, 21L, 32L), Distance = c(12L, 
    21L, 20L, 33L, 17L, 13L, 79L, 18L, 19L, 63L, 45L, 34L, 18L, 
    23L, 22L, 77L, 34L, 42L, 88L, 65L, 37L, 92L, 35L, 54L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: Can you post the dput of the starting data instead of the final data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we may use `pivot_wider` and join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
left_join(data2, pivot_wider(data2, names_from = 'Game', 
  values_from = c(Score, Distance), 
      names_glue = "{.value}Game{Game}"))
```

-output

```
   Player Game Score Distance ScoreGame0 ScoreGame1 ScoreGame2 ScoreGame3 ScoreGame4 ScoreGame5 ScoreGame6 ScoreGame7 ScoreGame8
1  Lebron James    0    32       12         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
2  Lebron James    1    23       21         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
3  Lebron James    2    33       20         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
4  Lebron James    3    27       33         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
5  Lebron James    4    29       17         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
6  Lebron James    5    27       13         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
7  Lebron James    6     4       34         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
8  Lebron James    7    88       33         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
9  Lebron James    8    23       29         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
10 Lebron James    9    34       48         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
11 Lebron James   10    54       60         32         23         33         27         29         27          4         88         23
12  Steph Curry    0    45       18         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
13  Steph Curry    1    48       23         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
14  Steph Curry    2    44       22         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
15  Steph Curry    3    51       77         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
16  Steph Curry    4    65       34         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
17  Steph Curry    5    76       42         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
18  Steph Curry    6    42       27         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
19  Steph Curry    7    44       41         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
20  Steph Curry    8    76       61         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
21  Steph Curry    9    40       58         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
22  Steph Curry   10    20       47         45         48         44         51         65         76         42         44         76
   ScoreGame9 ScoreGame10 DistanceGame0 DistanceGame1 DistanceGame2 DistanceGame3 DistanceGame4 DistanceGame5 DistanceGame6 DistanceGame7
1          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
2          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
3          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
4          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
5          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
6          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
7          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
8          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
9          34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
10         34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
11         34          54            12            21            20            33            17            13            34            33
12         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
13         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
14         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
15         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
16         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
17         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
18         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
19         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
20         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
21         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
22         40          20            18            23            22            77            34            42            27            41
   DistanceGame8 DistanceGame9 DistanceGame10
1             29            48             60
2             29            48             60
3             29            48             60
4             29            48             60
5             29            48             60
6             29            48             60
7             29            48             60
8             29            48             60
9             29            48             60
10            29            48             60
11            29            48             60
12            61            58             47
13            61            58             47
14            61            58             47
15            61            58             47
16            61            58             47
17            61            58             47
18            61            58             47
19            61            58             47
20            61            58             47
21            61            58             47
22            61            58             47
```

Comment: edited question slightly

Comment: @887 Not clear based on the edit.  Do you want a `filter` in between

Comment: @887 i.e. `left_join(data2, pivot_wider(data2 %>% filter(Game %in% seq(0, max(Game), 5)), names_from = 'Game', 
  values_from = c(Score, Distance), 
      names_glue = "{.value}Game{Game}"))`

Comment: yes, that worked! only way I tweaked it was by changing `seq (o, max(Game), 5` to `seq(0,30,5)` so that it would stop at 30 and go by intervals of 5. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  left_join(filter(.,Game %in% c(0,5,10))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Game, values_from = c(Score, Distance)))
    Player Game Score Distance Score_0 Score_5 Score_10 Distance_0 Distance_5 Distance_10
1  Lebron James    0    32       12      32      27       54         12         13          60
2  Lebron James    1    23       21      32      27       54         12         13          60
3  Lebron James    2    33       20      32      27       54         12         13          60
4  Lebron James    3    27       33      32      27       54         12         13          60
5  Lebron James    4    29       17      32      27       54         12         13          60
6  Lebron James    5    27       13      32      27       54         12         13          60
7  Lebron James    6     4       34      32      27       54         12         13          60
8  Lebron James    7    88       33      32      27       54         12         13          60
9  Lebron James    8    23       29      32      27       54         12         13          60
10 Lebron James    9    34       48      32      27       54         12         13          60
11 Lebron James   10    54       60      32      27       54         12         13          60
12  Steph Curry    0    45       18      45      76       20         18         42          47
13  Steph Curry    1    48       23      45      76       20         18         42          47
14  Steph Curry    2    44       22      45      76       20         18         42          47
15  Steph Curry    3    51       77      45      76       20         18         42          47
16  Steph Curry    4    65       34      45      76       20         18         42          47
17  Steph Curry    5    76       42      45      76       20         18         42          47
18  Steph Curry    6    42       27      45      76       20         18         42          47
19  Steph Curry    7    44       41      45      76       20         18         42          47
20  Steph Curry    8    76       61      45      76       20         18         42          47
21  Steph Curry    9    40       58      45      76       20         18         42          47
22  Steph Curry   10    20       47      45      76       20         18         42          47
```

Comment: what if i have multiple columns to join on? I tried the above solution on my full data set and it created ~500 columns...I think it's because I have multiple grouping variables. Could I add by = c("var1", "var2",....)?

Comment: apologies for not including that in the initial question, i tried to abbreviate the data so that the question would not be too cumbersome to read. Your solution works on the limited data provided, just not on the full set

Comment: edited initial question

Comment: @887 yes you can add the `by=c(....)`, but first select by